# Trying to run python 2 and python 3 on the same machine, having problems with 2.7 tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

I had python 2.7 on my machine running just fine. I decided to install python 3.3 on my computer and changed my environment variable path to C:\Python33 instead, intending that to be my main one. Running IDLE on python 3.3 works just fine, but for some reason, IDLE (and Tkinter) in python 2.7 no longer works. When I run the following command in the command prompt:

```
PS C:\python27\lib\idlelib> C:\python27\python.exe idle.py
** IDLE can't import Tkinter. Your python may not be configured for Tk. **
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, or my installation of 3.3 messed something up. Can anyone help?

Comment: `sys.path` should contain `'C:\python27\DLLs'`. Among other files that directory should contain _tkinter.pyd, tcl85.dll, tk85.dll, and tclpip85.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My memory isn't perfect...but for encountering this question much later and wondering, I ended up fixing my problem by uninstalling both versions (a pain, I know) and reinstalling with Python 3.3 **first** and Python 2.7 **second**. For some reason, after this I was able to run both versions of IDLE (in their respective folders) with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a idea but python  2.7 and 3.3 versions have minor differences on coding ex - input and raw input difference. So i think the version developers make  a exception if you run your 2.7 code on 3.3 compiler.

My suggestion better have 2 environment variables for both versions because as i told before syntax are different from 2.7 to 3.3 minor way .